# How to get sum value of usermeta key using another meta key

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have two meta key: us_points  &  agent_id

I need to sum up all the us_points value with agent ID same for each users.

Here is what I tried:

```
$cuser = wp_get_current_user(); $a_id = $cuser->agent_id; 
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT sum(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'us_points' AND agent_id = $a_id" );
echo $result[0];
```

If I remove AND agent_id = $a_id, it shows the sum of all users in the website, but I need to show the sum of only the meta key value common/matching in agent_id

Help will me much appreciated.

Comment: so, there is us_points and agent_id for each user? And you want sum of us_points for each agent_id?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Yes! us_points are either same or different for all users but agent_id is has common value for group of users. Like user a, b, c has agent_id 100, and their us_points varies as a=200, b=300, c=400.. so sum up the us_points with their common agent_id=100.. Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It should target agent_id meta key then group records by the same agent_id value before summing.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT sum(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'us_points' GROUP BY meta_value HAVING 'meta_key' = 'agent_id'" );
```

Comment: It won't work because I need to specify meta value. Like meta_key = $a_ids.

Comment: try then HAVING 'meta_key' = 'agent_id' AND 'meta_value' = $a_id

Comment: Still doesn't work.. this is my code : global $wpdb; $result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT sum(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'us_points' GROUP BY meta_value HAVING  'meta_key' = 'agent_id' AND 'meta_value' = '10'" );

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = get_users();
$agent_points = array();

foreach( $users as $user ) {
   $agent_points[] = array(
       'agent_id'  => $user->agent_id,
       'us_points' => $user->us_points,
   );
}
```

`$agent_points` expected to be in the structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 1
            [us_points] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 4
            [us_points] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 4
            [us_points] => 30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 1
            [us_points] => 20
        )
)
```

Then,

```
$results= array();

foreach( $agent_points as $values ) {
   foreach( $values as $key => $value ) {

        if( 'agent_id' === $key ) {
            $results[ $value ] += $values['us_points'];
        }
   }
}
```

Expected `$results` in `agent_id => us_points` pair:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 50
    [4] => 40
)
```